# Azure DevTest Lab: Set Mandatory artifacts programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-devtest-labs

we are trying to enable Mandatory Artifacts, in a DevTest Lab, programmatically.
we found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.devtestlab/2018-09-15/labs/policysets/policies#PolicyProperties

unfortunately we do not know the factName. Matter of fact, i am sure there are some policies on a lab i'm using for testing. I am not able to find any policy set with Azure Resource Explorer. I also enabled the Mandatory artifacts policy and even then no sign of any of this in Azure Resource Explorer.

Anyone experience with this?

best regards

Marc

Comment: Hi, @TonyJu. Could you point me towards the [meta] policy where adding [tag:azure] to questions that already have an [tag:azure-*] tag is allowed? Also, it might not be the best idea to do this before you have 2000 reputation, or too much in a given day (to avoid bumping old posts to the front page needlessly).

Answer (score 1):

Mandatory artifacts is a property on the lab itself. It is not a policy.

For example:

```
"mandatoryArtifactsResourceIdsWindows": ["/subscriptions/subId/resourceGroups/jraj-rg/providers/Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/jraj/artifactSources/public repo/artifacts/windows-7zip"],
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.devtestlab/2018-09-15/labs